# Is gRPC suitable for push notification?

Tags: asp.net-core, notifications, signalr, grpc, grpc-web

Currently I am using SignalR for push notification, but due to cost constrain looking for the new alternative. When I read about gRPC its mostly used for microservice communication. Will this gRPC is suitable for web push notification? is there any example I can find. Thanks.

Comment: In my opinion, the signalr is more easily for pushing notification, it has build-in library to long poling the server-side and the server side could easily push the notification to the client-side, if you use grpc should write all these logic by yourself. But grpc is also support the long poling.

Comment: grpc web supports bidirectional streaming ?

Comment: [gRPC does support bidirectional streaming.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/why-migrate-wcf-to-dotnet-grpc?view=aspnetcore-6.0#streaming)